# React Material Overlapping Header and Body

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a header that has a background image, but when a user scrolls, the header takes too long to change color and ends up overlapping with the body. Any tips on how i can prevent the header and body overlapping will be appreciated.
My code and how the page looks on scroll is as below

```
<div>

      <Header
        color="transparent"
        brand="Truhditions"
        rightLinks={<HeaderLinks />} 
        fixed
        changeColorOnScroll={{
          height: 200,
          color: "white"
        }}
        {...rest}
      />

    <Parallax small filter image={require("assets/img/profile-bg.jpg")} style={{height: 250}}/>


      <div className={classes.container} style={{background:"#E5E5E5"}}>
     
      <BusinessesSection category={rest.location.data} />
      </div>

      <Footer />
    </div>
```

[Current scrolling effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W19zA.png)

Expected scrolling effect :
[Expected scrolling effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrN5W.png)

Comment: Maybe your page is heavy in terms of performance so the scroll listener blocked for some time. Try to reproduce is with a simple page with only text or something. Maybe it's the Paralax which also might listen to on scroll. BTW, by `react-material` are you refer to https://github.com/creativetimofficial/nextjs-material-kit?

Comment: @MoshFeu yes, im using that template